# Updating session attributes every fixed time interval. Java, Servlets, JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'd like to update user session attributes (for example, user's money amount) every 20 minutes. How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Comment: A servlet will only execute when called by the browser/front-end/jsp  thus you'll have to get your some javascript to call the servelt every 20 minutes...  Or you can manipulate the session object using javascript

Comment: @TungstenX there are many ways to manipulate session attributes other than by calling a servlet. A session is just an object, which can be manipulated at any point in Java code. And it is not possible to manipulate (or even access) the session object directly from Javascript code.

Comment: @abl Of course one can get hold of the session object in Javascript: <% HttpSession s = request.getSession(false); %> and you are correct, on the Java side one can get hold of the session object under certain conditions.

Comment: @TungstenX I see no Javascript in your comment. That's a scriptlet.